# System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar is it possible to change the color of individual selections?

Tags: asp.net, controls, calendar

I have code to do multiple selections in a calendar control but I would like to change the color of the initially selected day to green and the end date to red.  Visually this would indicate the start date and end date of a certain service to be 
provided.  Should I be looking into RenderControl Method for my calander or more looking into setting some attribute of the days in the control?

The multiple select code is attributable to 
[Steve Wellins](http://weblogs.asp.net/SteveWellens/)

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar TheCalendar = sender as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar;

        // create new list of dates or get stored list of dates
        List SelectedDates;

        if (ViewState["SelectedDates"] == null)
            SelectedDates = new List();
        else
            SelectedDates = ViewState["SelectedDates"] as List;

        // if date is already in list, remove it, otherwise, add it
        if (SelectedDates.Contains(TheCalendar.SelectedDate) == false)
            SelectedDates.Add(Calendar1.SelectedDate);
        else
            SelectedDates.Remove(Calendar1.SelectedDate);

        // set the calendar to our list of dates
        TheCalendar.SelectedDates.Clear();
        foreach (DateTime Date in SelectedDates)
            TheCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(Date);

        // store list for next postback
        ViewState["SelectedDates"] = SelectedDates;
    }
```

---

This code may overwrite any date or formatting applied to the calendar but I am not above saving and restoring this formating to the calendar.

---

```
foreach (DateTime Date in SelectedDates)
                TheCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(Date);
```

I am glad to research leads if you point me down the right path or terms to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MSDN site the Calendar..::.OnDayRender Method is invoked while each day is being rendered.  I am a .NET noob... how to use it all?